# Backgrounds not appearing in firefox

Tags: css, firefox

I've not come across this problem before and can't seem to find a solution searching around. The problem is when I place a background using the following example the image will just not appear.

As you can see on chrome and the search bar should look like that, but on firefox its just a white box.

[chrome example](http://awesomescreenshot.com/0321syq9c2)

```
background: url(../images/facebook.png) 95 20 no-repeat;
```

It works absolutely fine in I.E and chrome just not firefox, is this something to do with the position integers or something else.

Thanks

Danny

Comment: What are `95` and `20`? Did you try adding units to them? (px, %, whatever they should be)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS doesn't have default units, so Firefox doesn't understand that you mean pixels. The other browsers just take a guess and help you out. Change it to:

`background: url(../images/facebook.png) 95px 20px no-repeat;`

and it should be fine.